# In Outlook C# VSTO get list of all Calendars

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, vsto, outlook-addin

How can I get list of all available calendars in Outlook?

I have two users logged in, and I can find them with this code:

```
        Outlook.NameSpace session = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session;
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = session.Accounts;
        Outlook.Account account = null;
        List<string> accountList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= accounts.Count; i++)
        {
            account = accounts[i];
            if (account != null)
                accountList.Add(account.DisplayName);
        }
```

How can I now get list of calendars per user? Or at least get list of all calendars mixed together?

Comment: "Available" in what sense? All stores already in the profile? Exchange mailboxes to which the current user has delegate access?

Comment: Two accounts are logged in and I need list of calendars from both.

Comment: What accounts? Exchange delegate mailboxes? Separate Exchange accounts? Google Apps accounts? IMAP4?

Answer (score 2):

You can use next code for solve this problem:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.NameSpace session = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session;
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = session.Accounts;
        List<Outlook.MAPIFolder> calendars = new List<Outlook.MAPIFolder>();

        foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient recipient = session.CreateRecipient(account.DisplayName);
            Outlook.MAPIFolder calendar = session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            if (calendar != null)
            {
                calendars.Add(calendar);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How I understand it will create calendars, not find them.

Comment: No, you have different users in your Outlook. For instance, you have user@user.one and user@user.two. If you use solution which i described previously, you can obtain calendars for these users, not create.

Comment: Ok, another thing: I just tested it, and you can find only default calendars with your code. You need to search in stores to find all calendars, but not only one per account.

Comment: Tried it out in a newer vsto project and it works quite well actually. See separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy of the suggested answer works quite well. I tried a similar solution to get the correct calendar for a specific user, like this:

```
var session = Application.Session;
var accounts = session.Accounts;
//get default calendar
var calendar = (MSOutlook.Folder)session.GetDefaultFolder(MSOutlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
//get calendar for specific user
foreach (MSOutlook.Account account in accounts)
{
    if (string.Equals(account.SmtpAddress, "someone@somewhere.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        var recipient = session.CreateRecipient(account.DisplayName);
        calendar = (MSOutlook.Folder)session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient,
            MSOutlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        break;
    }
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(session);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(accounts);
```